# Bounty not awarded in full (+300 vs +450)

Tags: support, bounty

To my delight, [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450395/874188) was awarded a bounty by the original OP after being the sole accepted answer for over a year.  The additional attention caused by the bounty garnered me a nice addition of upvotes, and the question got another answer.  When the bounty closed, I got awarded the bounty, apparently as the OP had intended.

*However,* in [my personal reputation stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee?tab=reputation), the bounty shows as +300 for that particular day (total +471 on Dec 15; the collapsed view shows +320 because there are two upvotes as well), while the badge on the question very clearly says that the OP meant to award +450.

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) says no reputation cap applies (that would make bounties for more than +200 pointless anyway).
The relationship is not 1/2 (that would be +225) so it's not a question of an automatically awarded bounty. [Clarification: Accepted answers and automatically awarded bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149160/clarification-accepted-answers-and-automatically-awarded-bounties) doesn't seem to have anything about this case, either.

Is this a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) or am I missing some documentation?

Comment: You've got 450 in total - 300 recently and 150 in the past...

Comment: @JonClements Is that so?  How could I find out?

Comment: You got awarded 150 on Nov 8th '14 see: http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=13

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Should I just delete this question then?

Comment: Doesn't it usually show two bounties as separate?

Comment: You shouldn't delete it. @jon-clemens should make his comment an answer you can accept.

Comment: @TinyGiant in the answer? No, I don't think I've ever seen bounties separated there.

Comment: Umm... I think the main question that would be useful for others here is "How could I find out?" - bounties don't appear to be on the post's timeline... http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26449944/timeline - I'm wondering what the convenient way is to see that's a result of multiple bounties... (not sure if "has been awarded bounties worth..." is useful as not sure if it says that for singular awards or not)

Comment: @eis I have seen multiple bounty badges on some answers IIRC.  Hard pressed to find an example I could link to but I speculate that the UI will show separate badges for each user who awarded bounties.

Comment: @JonClements That timeline link is one of the things I was hoping to see -- I've seen it in chat recently but stupidly didn't bookmark it at the time.  Is that documented anywhere?  The fact that it doesn't show bounties is certainly a [tag:bug] IMHO.

Comment: We should ask for the timeline to be [improved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254335/288751).

Comment: @TinyGiant If it's slated to be removed anyway, as stated in the answer you link to, asking for improvements is probably moot.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the #irony hash-tag there. :) IMO, It's a great resource, which should be improved upon or replaced with something even better instead of being left in a corner to rot.

Comment: Now that I know what to search for, I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/faq-for-how-to-access-questions-timeline

Comment: I posted a [tag:feature-request] after all: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312833/timeline-page-aka-activity-log-does-not-show-bounties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JonClements was able to tell me, the bounty was awarded in pieces -- +150 before, and +300 this week.  Nothing is wrong (apart from the fact that there is really no simple way to find out, short of browsing your reputation history).

Comment: You can see it in [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26450395/revisions) and [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26450395/timeline)

Comment: Yeah, the revisions have been revamped after I posted this question. The timeline was showing 300 then, as it does now, which is what made me ask.