# Timeline page (aka activity log) does not show bounties

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty, timeline

As [vividly illustrated in a recent question of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312828/bounty-not-awarded-in-full-300-vs-450) the [timeline view of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/faq-for-how-to-access-questions-timeline) continues to be useful, but fails to include information about bounties.  Could they be added there, please?

Comment: The current timeline implementation [isn't supported and won't get any improvements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270438/shouldnt-the-timeline-view-show-votes-that-have-been-removed#comment876248_270438), although you could ask for this in the next implementation....

Comment: @NathanTuggy The comment you link to is followed by another which says the new implementation is already done, though not yet rolled out for general availability.  I really don't see how the version number or provenance of the code matters here -- if the next version doesn't have this feature, this [tag:feature-request] will still be valid, and if it does, it can be closed.

Comment: The new implementation may or may not use the same URL scheme, so you might want to reword to make it clear that you're talking about *all* timeline views. (Also, posting a feature-request ahead of time seems likely to lead to its being forgotten more easily.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for the suggestion; feel free to edit further if you still see room for improvement. The timing is not something I can easily affect, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: With the new timeline you can now see the bounty information: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26450395/timeline